# getClass().getResource and getClass().getClassLoader().getResource return Null

Tags: java, classloader

I want to use some image in my application. But, I do not want to hard code the image path because where ever I stored the application it should works.

I tried to use `getClass().getResource` and `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource` but in both cases I am getting `NULL`.

here is the actual path for the image:

```
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\MyApplication\ViewController\public_html\resources\images\img.gif
```

and here is the actual path for the class I am working with:

```
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\MyApplication\ViewController\src\view\MyClassBean
```

So both the class and the image in the same project `ViewController`

here is the output statements from `MyClassBean` Class:

```
        System.out.println("1. "+  getClass());
        System.out.println("2. "+  getClass().getClassLoader());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1. "+  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("img.gif") );
        System.out.println("2. "+  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("3. "+  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("4. "+  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("5. "+  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("6. "+  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("7. "+  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("8. "+  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("9. "+  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("ViewController/public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("10. "+ getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/ViewController/public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("11. "+ getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myApplication/ViewController/public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("12. "+ getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/myApplication/ViewController/public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1. "+  getClass().getResource("img.gif") );
        System.out.println("2. "+  getClass().getResource("/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("3. "+  getClass().getResource("images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("4. "+  getClass().getResource("/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("5. "+  getClass().getResource("resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("6. "+  getClass().getResource("/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("7. "+  getClass().getResource("public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("8. "+  getClass().getResource("/public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("9. "+  getClass().getResource("ViewController/public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("10. "+ getClass().getResource("/ViewController/public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("11. "+ getClass().getResource("myApplication/ViewController/public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
        System.out.println("12. "+ getClass().getResource("/myApplication/ViewController/public_html/resources/images/img.gif") );
```

here is the output Results:

```
1. class view.MyClassBean
2. weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader@16a1d36 finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@a94081 annotation: MyApplication@MyApplication-ViewController-context-root
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.  null
2.  null
3.  null
4.  null
5.  null
6.  null
7.  null
8.  null
9.  null
10. null
11. null
12. null
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.  null
2.  null
3.  null
4.  null
5.  null
6.  null
7.  null
8.  null
9.  null
10. null
11. null
12. null
```

So, How Can I get any image that stored in the same project where the running class is with in the `java` code.

I am using `JDeveloper 11g Release 2` with `ADF` technology.

Comment: Really? None of the questions/answers here on SO that already cover this were of any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
//something like that     
getClass().getResource("../../../public_html/resources/images/img.gif")
```

I mean the file path base on your project target folder or bin folder.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please learn how to format code snippets properly. Also, it would help if you gave an explanation for why your answer works.